# Why is length of "Níðhöggr" 9?

Tags: haskell, unicode

Why is the `length` function saying that this 8 character string is 9 characters?

```
>>> length "Níðhöggr"
9
```

Comment: It's probably canonically decomposed...

Comment: Is it my imagination or are all of your Haskell questions deliberate trick questions?

Comment: What I find interesting is that the diaresis appears above the first `'g'` here, while it is displayed above the `'o'` when I copy and paste. I wonder how that comes.

Comment: @DanielFischer: It's probably your browser. It looks correct here using Chrome 27 on Linux.

Comment: @hammar Correct meaning the diaresis is above the `'o'`?

Comment: @DanielFischer It's either the browser or the font (or a combination). I also see the diæresis above the `g` in `Níðhöggr`, but in "Níðhöggr" it's where it should be (above the o).

Comment: @PetrViktorin Something like that, it's above the `'g'` in FireFox and Seamonkey, and above the `'o'` in Konqueror in the question body, above the `'o'` in the title everywhere.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Yes, it's above the `'o'`.

Comment: Its funny because in the title of the question I see 9 characters. It seems kinda self explanatory :)

Comment: `Prelude> mapM_ print ("Níðhöggr" :: String)
'N'
'\237'
'\240'
'h'
'o'
'\776'
'g'
'g'
'r'`

Comment: @HonzaBrabec By sight, I count 8 characters and 2 types of accents, so I'm not sure what you're seeing...  =P

Comment: @HonzaBrabec Oh, you mean the _browser's_ titlebar, not the title of the question!  I do indeed see a "broken" character between the `o` and `g` there, making 9.

Comment: @DanielFischer: That's a clear telltale that the diaeresis is a combining character and that your various apps handle them differently. Firefox has its own custom Unicode font rendering code if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: OSX prefers the combining characters instead of the single symbol character with äöü.

Comment: Prelude> "Níðhöggr" ==  "Níðhöggr" ; 
False

Answer (score 64, accepted):

"Níðhöggr" contains 9 Unicode characters:

```
U+004E N (Lu): LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N 
U+00ED í (Ll): LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH ACUTE
U+00F0 ð (Ll): LATIN SMALL LETTER ETH 
U+0068 h (Ll): LATIN SMALL LETTER H 
U+006F o (Ll): LATIN SMALL LETTER O 
U+0308 ̈ (Mn): COMBINING DIAERESIS 
U+0067 g (Ll): LATIN SMALL LETTER G 
U+0067 g (Ll): LATIN SMALL LETTER G 
U+0072 r (Ll): LATIN SMALL LETTER R
```

You might want to use "Níðhöggr", which looks the same when printed out, but contains `U+00F6 LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS` instead of the two-character ö combo. In other words, it is in the *composed* normal form (NFC).

Or you might want "Níðhöggr", which has 10 Unicode characters (the í is split int `i` and a combining accent). That would be *decomposed* normal form (NFD).

Google "Unicode normalization" for interesting and/or hairy details. Use [this function](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text-icu/0.6.3.5/doc/html/Data-Text-ICU-Normalize.html#v:normalize) to normalize Unicode data in Haskell (thanks, Adam Rosenfield!).

Comment: What? This sounds like an encoding issue/implementation detail. Is there a function that gives the real length?

Comment: @Dog, the real length in terms of Unicode characters *is* 9. If you want something else, you may wish to perform conversion to a Unicode normalization form.

Comment: @Dog It's the real length, the string consists of 9 code points. A `Char` is a code point (not character).

Comment: @Dog: If you want the length of the normalized string, then you should normalize it first with the [`normalize` function](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text-icu/0.6.3.5/doc/html/Data-Text-ICU-Normalize.html#v:normalize) before getting its `length`.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I don't know what you consider the real length, but I want the number of letters.

Comment: @DanielFischer: A symbol, sorry I don't know the real name for it. I'd expect it to give 8 for this string.

Comment: @Dog `length $ filter Data.Char.isLetter "Níðhöggr"`.

Comment: @DanielFischer that doesn't do what I want (e.g numbers aren't counted), normalization seems to be what I want.

Comment: @Dog: I think you want to read [this](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries).

Comment: @Dog: In particular, [Data.Text.ICU.Break.breakCharacter](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text-icu/0.6.3.5/doc/html/Data-Text-ICU-Break.html) seems to break the text into just the right units. Note that this operation is locale-dependent (e.g. `ll` is a single character in some languages and two characters in others, which may be important).

Comment: It's a good idea to avoid the term "character" when dealing with Unicode. Unfortunately these days it is not a technical term. "Code unit", "code point", and "glyph" are various technical terms which cover different aspects of what "character" can mean.

Answer (score 21):

Because your `ö` isn't the single character `ö` (U+00F6 LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS); it's U+006F LATIN SMALL LETTER O plus U+0308 COMBINING DIAERESIS.